# When generally talking a concept, should I use plural or singular?

Tags: word-usage

Person A is trying to distinguish towns and cities with concrete examples.

> A: "What are **the famous towns** in the UK or Ireland?"
>
> B: "Well in the UK, you have cities like London, Manchester, Edinburgh
>   and Cardiff among others."
>
> B: "While Irish cities aren't as famous but Dublin, Cork and Galway
>   are some of them."
>
> B: "Towns aren't really as famous outside of their countries."
>
> A: "Sorry for misleading. I meant any town, not necessarily **a famous town**."

Person A uses both plural and singular, are those 2 uses both correct?

---

similar situation

> Imagine you are planning to visit another city or town. What type of **place** do you look for?

Comment: Yes, of course, because they are in two different contexts.

Comment: A is asking which towns - not necessarily famous ones - are famous. Is that right?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian A is asking about some names of towns that are not cities to distinguish towns and cities with concrete examples.

Comment: A's answer could have been "I meant any towns, not necessarily famous towns." It's not wrong that they switched to singular, though.